# making the chat help for inline references more clear

Tags: feature-request, chat, onebox, chat-faq

The chat help includes the line "Some links will be automatically inlined if posted on a single line by themselves, such as":

[image]

I interpreted this "oneboxing" as only having to do <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>paste-in-url<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. This resulted in the URL on a line by its own, but did not expand.

What I needed to do was actually press <kbd>Enter</kbd> before and after **and provide the link in a post sent on its own**. Could the help be reworded to make this less ambiguous?

[image]